For boost::fibonacci_heap, does pop() API automatically update the heap? Or is it necessary to follow it with update()?
I am new to using boost::fibonacci_heap and had some questions regarding usage. I have read the user manual, the answer is not clear: "https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct heapEle {
  boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<heapEle>::handle_type myhandle;
  unsigned gain;
  std::string name;
  bool valid;
  heapEle(unsigned gain, std::string name) :
    gain(gain),
    name(name), valid(true) {}
  heapEle() :
    gain(0),
    name(""), valid(true) {}
  bool operator < (const heapEle &qB) const {
    return gain < qB.gain;
  }
};

int main() {

  boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<heapEle> myheap;
  std::vector<boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<heapEle>::handle_type> handleVec;
  boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<heapEle>::handle_type temphandle;

  temphandle = myheap.push(heapEle(20, "apple"));
  (*temphandle).myhandle = temphandle;
  handleVec.push_back(temphandle);
  temphandle = myheap.push(heapEle(10, "banana"));
  (*temphandle).myhandle = temphandle;
  handleVec.push_back(temphandle);
  temphandle = myheap.push(heapEle(30, "cherry"));
  (*temphandle).myhandle = temphandle;
  handleVec.push_back(temphandle);
  temphandle = myheap.push(heapEle(50, "pineapple"));
  (*temphandle).myhandle = temphandle;
  handleVec.push_back(temphandle);
  temphandle = myheap.push(heapEle(40, "papaya"));
  (*temphandle).myhandle = temphandle;
  handleVec.push_back(temphandle);

  std::cout << "Top of heap is " << myheap.top().name << std::endl;
  temphandle = myheap.top().myhandle;
  
  myheap.pop();
  (*temphandle).valid = false;

  int i = 1;
  for (int j = 0; j < handleVec.size(); j++) {
    if (!((*(handleVec[j])).valid))
      continue;
    
    (*(handleVec[j])).gain = 200*i++;
    myheap.update(handleVec[j]);
  }

  std::cout << "New top of heap is " << myheap.top().name << std::endl;
  for(const heapEle& n : myheap) {
    std::cout << n.name << " " << n.gain << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

My questions:

Does "(*temphandle).valid = false"  cause invalid access to freed memory, as I just did pop() before this? Is it correct usage?
Do calls to myheap.update(handleVec[j]) cause invalid access to the element freed by pop()?

I am new to using boost, any help would be appreciated.

@close voters - what debugging details do you expect? The question asks about usage of a specific class, not debugging.

@Yksisarvinen The question is "Am I causing invalid access to freed memory?" that should follow a [mre]. "Do I need to call update after pop" can be answered after reading the data structure manual.


pop: Effects: Removes the top element from the priority queue.
update: Effects: Updates the heap after the element handled by handle has been changed.

pop is removing the top element from the priority queue so it is no longer inside the queue when you are to update it. So, unless you have evidence of the contrary, it should not cause the behavior you were worried about.
